Googleスプレットシートの#ERROR！と先頭のゼロが消えてしまうことに関して
①Googleスプレットシートで
お客様の名前を集計しているのですが
一部に#ERROR！という表示が出てきて、正しい文字を表示をする方法は分かるのですが、毎日Excelからデータをコピーアンドペーストして更新しているので、その度に#ERROR！表示に戻ってしまうので手動で修正しているのですが
例えばですが、関数や数式を使って更新があっても#ERROR！表示にならないようにする方法はないかなどを調べております。
②Googleスプレットシートで先頭のゼロが消えてしまい、0を表示する方法は分かるのですが
#ERROR!の時と同じように毎日更新があったり
ページを閉じてしまうと戻ってしまいます。
パソコンは素人なので、簡単な方法だとありがたいです。
何か解決策はありますでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

スプレッドシート側で書式設定等を行った状態なのであれば、コピー＆ペースト時に単純な貼り付けではなく、右クリック → 特殊貼り付け → 値のみ貼り付け を試してみてください。

cubick様 ご返信いただきましてありがとうございます！ フォローさせていただきました。ご教授いただいた特殊貼り付け値のみは元々使っておりました。IFERROR関数を使って修正をしてみたのですが、正しい文字の表示はできるのですが、やはり更新のたびに#ERROR!表示に戻ってしまいますね。私の素人なものでなかなか難しいことなのかもしれません。
